# Google distance matrix api quota behaves unreliable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I'm talking specifically about the quota of type **elements per minute per user**. I set this value to 150. The documentation says number of elements is **origins x destinations**.

This is how I call the api:

```
const distanceMatrixService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
const request = {
    origins: [locator.searchLocation.location],
    destinations: locator.locations.map(function (x) {
        return x.coords;
    }),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: units,
};
distanceMatrixService.getDistanceMatrix(request, distancesReceivedCallback);
```

I get a proper response having 1 origin and `locator.locations` contains 3 destinations. As far as I add a 4th destination I receive an error response:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "error_message" : "Distance Matrix Service: You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API.",
   "origin_addresses" : [],
   "rows" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

The other quotas are all set to a very high value so they should not be a problem.

**Why am I exceeding the quota of 150 with 4 destinations but not with 3?**

From the documentation my requests should count as 4 (1 x 4) elements. The only way the api works reliable is when I set this specific quota to unlimited which is not desireable for my use case.

Comment: Is this only 1 API call?

Comment: @Yrll Yes, I made sure it is only one call from the network tab of the dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Elements Per Minute / 60 = Elements per second

**Elements per minute** seems to have been misunderstood. From what I can see, the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error appears because the quotas you have set is working as intended.

Let me explain how **Elements Per Minute Work**:

When setting up your quota using **Elements Per Minute**, you should divide it with **60** to get **Elements Per Second**. The result would be your maximum query "every" second. So when you have set your **Elements Per Minute** to 150, this means that your maximum **Elements Per Second** is at 2.5 Elements.

```
150 Elements per minute / 60 = 2.5 Elements per second
```

The API might be rounding up the 2.5 to 3 and that explains why you are not receiving an `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error if you implement 3 elements (1 origin x 3 destinations) and receive it when you implement 4 elements (1 origin x 4 destinations) because, ofcourse, you are **"OVER"** the quota of elements per second that you have set.

I hope this answers your question. And please feel free to confirm it in the comments if this fixed your issue.

Comment: I just ran some tests and it seems about right. As you already mentioned google seems to somehow round so I couldn't verify it exactly. Thanks a lot! It could really be documented better.